# Can't find a proper way to close Java Spark session(with spark version 2.2.1)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm deploy a spark on yarn driver java application,it will submit spark jobs(mainly doing some offline statistics over hive,elasticsearch and hbase) to cluster when Task Scheduling System gives it a task call.So I make this driver app keep running,always wait for request.

I use thread pool to handle task calls,Every task will open a new
SparkSession and close it when job finished(we skip multiple tasks
call at the same time scenario to simplify this question).Java code should be like this:

```
SparkSession sparkSession=SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
......doing statistics......
sparkSession.close();
```

This app compiled and running under jdk8 and memory related configured as fellow:

```
spark.ui.enabled=false
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory=2G  
--driver-java-options "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2048M -XX:+UseG1GC"
```

At first glance I thought this driver app will consumes at most 4G memories,but as it keeps running,TOP shows it takes more and more resident size.
I dumped it's heap file and saw many Spark related instances left in threadLocal after sparksession closed,such as Hive metastore,SparkSession itself.After many study,I find Spark using a lot of threadlocals and havn't remove them(or I just havn't use the right way to close sparksession) I add those codes to clear threadlocals that spark left behind:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState;
......
SparkSession.clearDefaultSession();
sparkSession.close();
Hive.closeCurrent();
SessionState.detachSession();
SparkSession.clearActiveSession();
```

This seems work for now,but I think it's just not decent enough,I'm wondering is there a better way to do it like another single spark java api can do all the cleaning?I just can't find a clue from spark document.